# How do i make sure my collected signature on wpf is legal in court

Tags: c#, wpf, certificate, digital-signature

**the context:**

I am currently creating a WPF application for a windows tablet. this application should replace a paper work from. the current paper form is a sheet of paper on which a serviceman writes the hours he spend on the job, the materials he used and what he did while he was there.
when the job is done he shows this form to the customer and the customer signs it. the company wants to digitalise it and I've been writing a user control for capturing signatures. I have used this tutorial as an example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480678.aspx. although it is in vb I've used the same encryption mechanism in C#
the american government (although I'm from the netherlands about the same rules apply so i thought i'd refference something in english) says the following about a digital signature:
http://usgovinfo.about.com/library/bills/bldigitalsigs.htm
to store all data to which the customer signs is stored in serialized data classes (using MVVM pattern so it's quite easy to get all the data together)

I've done quit some research on digital signatures but the more i read about it the more i'm afraid i just can't make it my self.

**the question:**
how do i obtain a valid certificate to make sure the signature is valid.

And it's actually a partial 2nd question..
how do i encrypt my data with that signature so there's no question about that data being signed for

**some code:**
the encryption method:

```
public void Encrypt(InkSecureSignatureData signatureData)
        {

            try
            {
                // Block sizes and buffer for stream operations.
                const int SMALLEST = 86;
                const int BLOCK = 128;
                byte[] Buffer = new byte[SMALLEST];
                // Variables for Ink data.
                StrokeCollection CopyOfSourceInk = new StrokeCollection();
                StrokeCollection WashedInk = new StrokeCollection();
                // Serialized signature objects.
                System.IO.MemoryStream SourceStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                System.IO.MemoryStream EncryptedStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

                signatureData.BiometricEncryptionSubmittedOn = DateTime.Now;

                // Store the machine name in the HardwareInfo property.
                signatureData.HardwareInfo = Environment.MachineName;

                // Create a working copy of the SignatureData's ink.
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(signatureData.InkSecureSignature))
                {
                    CopyOfSourceInk = new System.Windows.Ink.StrokeCollection(ms);
                    ms.Close();
                }
                //CopyOfSourceInk.Load(signatureData.InkSecureSignature);

                // Wash each Stroke by using GetFlattenedBezierPoints
                // to remove all pressure information.
                foreach (Stroke Stroke in CopyOfSourceInk)
                {
                    //WashedInk.CreateStroke(Stroke.GetFlattenedBezierPoints(500));
                    WashedInk.Add(new Stroke(Stroke.GetBezierStylusPoints()));
                }

                //signatureData.InkWashedSignature = WashedInk.Save(PersistenceFormat.InkSerializedFormat, CompressionMode.Default);
                byte[] signature;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    WashedInk.Save(ms);
                    signature = ms.ToArray();
                }
                signatureData.InkWashedSignature = signature;

                // Create a key and establish RSAKeyInfo.
                byte[] PublicKey = {//some huge as byte array which i'm not gonna add here}
                byte[] Exponent = {
                1,
                0,
                1
            };
                RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = new RSAParameters();
                RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = PublicKey;
                RSAKeyInfo.Exponent = Exponent;
                System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

                // Serialize the signature.
                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer Serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(InkSecureSignatureData));
                Serializer.Serialize(SourceStream, signatureData);

                // Cycle through the in-memory stream and encrypt it.
                SourceStream.Position = 0;

                while ((SourceStream.Read(Buffer, 0, SMALLEST) >= SMALLEST))
                {
                    if ((SourceStream.Position < SourceStream.Length))
                    {
                        EncryptedStream.Write(RSA.Encrypt(Buffer, true), 0, BLOCK);
                    }
                }

                // Handle the remaining bytes in the stream.
                long Amount = SourceStream.Length % SMALLEST;
                byte[] Remaining = new byte[Amount];
                Array.Copy(Buffer, Remaining, Amount);
                EncryptedStream.Write(RSA.Encrypt(Remaining, true), 0, BLOCK);

                // Place the encrypted data in the InkSecureSignatureData object.
                signatureData.EncryptedBiometricData = EncryptedStream.ToArray();
                signatureData.BiometricEncryptionCompletedOn = DateTime.Now;

                // Blank out the original signature to prevent expropriation.
                signatureData.InkSecureSignature = null;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

the partial class in which i collect the signature:

```
public partial class DrawSignatureScreen : Window
    {
        // Locks the signature.
        private bool signatureReadOnly;
        // The caption for the signer's name.
        private string signersNameCaptionValue = "Signer's Name: ";

        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when the signature has been fully signed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source InkSecureSignature object for this event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The EventArgs object that contains the event data.</param>
        public event SignedEventHandler Signed;
        public delegate void SignedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

        public DrawSignatureScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            signatureInkCanvas.StrokeCollected += signatureInkOverlay_Stroke;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the override to the default "Signer's Name:" label caption.
        /// </summary>
        public string SignersNameCaption
        {
            get
            {
                return signersNameCaptionValue;
            }
            set
            {
                signersNameCaptionValue = value;
                signersNameLabel.Content = signersNameCaptionValue;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets whether the signature has been completed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// After the signature is accepted, this property is true, and
        /// it cannot be changed back to false. This would enable the
        /// modification of the signature after acceptance.
        /// </remarks>
        public bool SignatureComplete
        {
            get
            {
                return signatureReadOnly;
            }
            set
            {
                // If the signature is already accepted, then exit.
                if ((signatureReadOnly == true) | (value == signatureReadOnly))
                {
                    return;
                }
                // Because we got this far, Value is True, 
                // so lock all controls and disable Ink collection.
                acceptButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                if ((signatureInkCanvas != null))
                {
                    signatureInkCanvas.IsEnabled = false;
                }
                signersNameTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                // Set the signer's name label control to the current caption for 
                // the signer's name plus the actual signer's name.
                signersNameLabel.Content = signersNameCaptionValue + (this.DataContext as InkSecureSignatureData).SignersName;

                // Set the read-only property value.
                signatureReadOnly = value;
                cancelButton.Content = "OK";
            }
        }
        //
        // SetDefaultDrawingAttributes
        //
        // Set the default drawing attributes for ink collection.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //  color - The desired ink color.
        //

        private void SetDefaultDrawingAttributes(System.Drawing.Color color)
        {
            var _with1 = signatureInkCanvas.DefaultDrawingAttributes;
            // Color.
            _with1.Color = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
            // Smooth.
            //_with1.AntiAliased = true;
            _with1.FitToCurve = true;
            // Set to not round (modify) the Stroke.
            //_with1.PenTip = PenTip.Ball;
            _with1.StylusTip = StylusTip.Ellipse;
            // Ball Point.
            _with1.Width = 2;
            // Size.
        }

        // signatureInkOverlay_Stroke
        //
        // On the first Stroke, set the timestamp and button state.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //  sender - The source InkOverlay object for this event.
        //  e - The InkCollectorStrokeEventArgs object that contains the event data.
        // 

        private void signatureInkOverlay_Stroke(object sender, InkCanvasStrokeCollectedEventArgs e)
        {
            // First, check to ensure that this is the first Stroke, otherwise exit.
            if (signatureInkCanvas.Strokes.Count > 1)
            {
                return;
            }
            // Set the Acquired Signature Start On to Now.
            (this.DataContext as InkSecureSignatureData).AcquiredSignatureStartOn = DateTime.Now;

            // Enable the clear button.
            clearButton.IsEnabled = true;

            // Call ValidateData to see if all of the required
            // criteria has been met to "accept" the signature.
            ValidateData();

        }

        //
        // signersNameTextBox_TextChanged
        //
        // Occurs when the Text property value changes.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //  sender - The source TextBox object for this event.
        //  e - The EventArgs object that contains the event data.
        // 

        private void signersNameTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Assign the signer's name from the text box to the underlying data object.
            (this.DataContext as InkSecureSignatureData).SignersName = signersNameTextBox.Text;
            ValidateData();
        }

        //
        // clearButton_Click
        //
        // Occurs when the Button is clicked to clear the signature in process.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //  sender - The source Button object for this event.
        //  e - The EventArgs object that contains the event data.
        // 
        private void clearButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SignatureComplete = false;
            signatureReadOnly = false;
            // Delete the Strokes collection.
            signatureInkCanvas.Strokes.Clear();
            // Disable the clear button.
            clearButton.IsEnabled = false;
            signersNameTextBox.Text = "";
            signersNameLabel.Content = "Signer's name:";
            signatureInkCanvas.IsEnabled = true;
            SetDefaultDrawingAttributes(Color.Black);
            // Revalidate the data.
            ValidateData();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Prints the signature.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="graphics">The Graphics context to print to.</param>
        /// <param name="topLeftPoint">The top left corner of the print area.</param>

        public void Print(Graphics graphics, System.Drawing.Point topLeftPoint)
        {
            // Starting locations.
            int Indentation = 5;
            int BottomLineY = 17;
            int VerticalLocation = (int)topLeftPoint.Y;

            // Specify a bordered print area slightly smaller than the control.
            Rectangle ThisRect = new Rectangle(topLeftPoint.X, topLeftPoint.Y, 800, 281);
            Color BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 45, 150);
            Microsoft.Ink.Renderer Renderer = new Microsoft.Ink.Renderer();

            var _with2 = graphics;
            _with2.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, ThisRect);
            _with2.DrawRectangle(new Pen(BorderColor), ThisRect);

            // Draw the bottom line.
            _with2.DrawLine(Pens.Black, Indentation, ThisRect.Height - BottomLineY, ThisRect.Width - (2 * Indentation), ThisRect.Height - BottomLineY);

            if (SignatureComplete == false)
            {
                // Draw a blank signature line.
                _with2.DrawString("Signed: ", new Font(new System.Drawing.FontFamily("arial"),10f), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), ThisRect.Left + Indentation, ThisRect.Height - BottomLineY + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                // Draw header text and washed Ink.
                _with2.DrawString("RSA Encrypted Digital Biometric Signature", new Font(new System.Drawing.FontFamily("arial"), 10f), new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), ThisRect.Left + 3, VerticalLocation + 3);

                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
                graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;

                StrokeCollection sc = signatureInkCanvas.Strokes;
                byte[] inkData = null;
                using (MemoryStream inkMemStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    sc.Save(inkMemStream);
                    inkData = inkMemStream.ToArray();
                }
                Ink ink = new Ink();
                ink.Load(inkData);

                Microsoft.Ink.DrawingAttributes da = new Microsoft.Ink.DrawingAttributes(Color.Black);
                da.AntiAliased = true;
                da.FitToCurve = false;
                da.RasterOperation = RasterOperation.Black;
                foreach (Microsoft.Ink.Stroke Stroke in ink.Strokes)
                {
                    Renderer.Draw(graphics, Stroke, da);
                }

                _with2.DrawString("Signed By: " + (this.DataContext as InkSecureSignatureData).SignersName.ToString() + " on " + (this.DataContext as InkSecureSignatureData).SignerAcceptedOn.ToString(), new Font(new System.Drawing.FontFamily("arial"), 10f), new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), ThisRect.Left + Indentation, ThisRect.Height - BottomLineY + 1);
            }
        }

        //public void Reset()
        //{
        //    (this.DataContext as Collection).Signatures = "<InkSecureSignatureData/>";

        //}

        //
        // acceptButton_Click
        //
        // Occurs when the Button is clicked to lock the signature.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //  sender - The source Button object for this event.
        //  e - The EventArgs object that contains the event data.
        // 

        private void acceptButton_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var _with3 = (this.DataContext as InkSecureSignatureData);
            // Save the serialized Ink to the SignatureData.InkSecureSignature property
            // for encryption by the Biometric Encryption Provider for Ink.

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            signatureInkCanvas.Strokes.Save(ms);
            _with3.InkSecureSignature = ms.ToArray();

            _with3.SignerAcceptedOn = DateTime.Now;

            BiometricEncryptionProviderForInk BiometricEncryptionProvider = new BiometricEncryptionProviderForInk();

            try
            {
                // Wash and encrypt the signature data.
                BiometricEncryptionProvider.Encrypt((this.DataContext as InkSecureSignatureData));

                // Stop collecting Ink and show the washed Ink.
                this.SignatureComplete = true;
                //CreateNewInkCanvas();
                SetDefaultDrawingAttributes(Color.Black);

                ms = new MemoryStream((this.DataContext as InkSecureSignatureData).InkWashedSignature);
                signatureInkCanvas.Strokes = new StrokeCollection(ms);

                System.Drawing.Bitmap signatureBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(803, 284, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

                //Create a graphics context from that bitmap image.
                Graphics graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(signatureBitmap);

                // Print the InkSecureSignature to the bitmap.
                Print(graphics, new System.Drawing.Point(1, 1));

                ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
                _with3.Signature = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(signatureBitmap, typeof(byte[]));

                // Clean up.
                graphics.Dispose();

                //TODO remove when done with testing
                signatureBitmap.Save("test.Jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                // Tell the calling form that the control is done processing.
                if (Signed != null)
                {
                    Signed(this, new EventArgs());
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        //
        // ValidateData
        //
        // Sets the Accept button's state depending on the presence of required inputs.
        //

        private void ValidateData()
        {
            acceptButton.IsEnabled = (signatureInkCanvas.Strokes.Count > 0) && (signersNameTextBox.Text.Length > 0);
            if (!acceptButton.IsEnabled)
            {
                acceptButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                signersNameTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
    }
```

the fields in the class `InkSecureSignatureData` i use to store all (encrypted) data collected from the signature:

```
private System.DateTime mAcquiredSignatureStartOn;
private System.DateTime mBiometricEncryptionSubmittedOn;
private System.DateTime mBiometricEncryptionCompletedOn;
private byte[] mEncryptedBiometricData;
private string mHardwareInfo;
private byte[] mInkWashedSignature;
private byte[] mInkSignature;
private System.DateTime mSignerAcceptedOn;
private byte[] signatureBitmap;
private string mSignersName;
```

finally i have a Class called 'Collection' which stores all data that has been entered it also stores the class which also contains the class `InkSecureSignatureData`.

i hope i have provided enough information, if something is not clear please ask and i'll try to answer.

Comment: Hi again, if my answer helped, you can accept and upvote it. Thak you and good luck with your project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Difference between digital signature and digitized signature**

You're mixing something up here: A *digital signature* is an asymmetric cryptographic algorithm and has nothing to with writing down your name, neither old-school pen-and-paper style nor on a any digital device. It is called digital signature because it can be used with the same purpose: Make sure that data

1. **authentic** (i.e. that when the letter says 'Yours, mom', it was
   actually your mom who wrote it)
2. **original** (i.e. that nobody modified your mom's letter's content after your mom wrote it)

Now, what the actual hand-written signature is in analog real-life is the *private key* in the digital signature world. This definition of *digital signature* is what for example this US government thing relates to.

The second thing you're talking about is digitizing the handwritten signature. A digitized handwritten signature is not a *digital signature*.

Anyway, there are lots of reasons to mix these completely different concepts. A digital signature algorithm can be used to make sure that a digitally recorded handwritten signature is *authentic* and *original*, for example. This is what the tutorial you've mentioned is about.

That being said, the main question is: *What are your requirements?* Especially regarding security.

**Solution principle**

I would start from here: The main goal is to bind a *digitized signature* to your dataset in a way that the dataset cannot be altered afterwards. As a concept, the following algorithm would achieve this goal:

Given the data, and the digitized signature in whatever format (`InkSecureSignature` is fine here, the important thing is that the signature needs to be present in a format that prohibits misuse. This means, the quality of the data needs to be "sufficiently bad"):

Define a class which holds the data and the signature an serialize it.

Create a random public and private key pair (APub, APriv).

Use a digital signature algorithm to sign the data (enrypted or original)

Destroy key *APriv*.

Save the data together with key *APub*.

Now, with key *APub* you will be able to check that data and *digitized signature* have been packed together and have not altered since.

**That's not it, of course**

The solution above is highly insecure. The worst part is, that, although a record, once stored in the database, cannot be altered, it could be replaced and nobody would notice. To avoid this, you need a *certificate*, more or less the same as a pair of a private and a public key (I hope I don't get slaughtered for this) which is the only instance with the right to sign data. Security of your system then melts down to making sure your certificate doesn't get in the wrong people's hands. You could consider a webservice which requests signing the data on a central server. You need to secure the communication channel, again with encryption and digital signing. Each device would have its own certificate. That way you could track everything on the server: Which device requested what signature at what time with what certificate. This would probably come close to a system that would be accepted by legal authorities (Don't nail me down to this).

**If your software could be hacked**

Secondly, one could use a *digitized signature* which is already present in the database, to sign new data. There is hardly any secure solution, as long as you have to consider somebody to manipulate your software on code level. Alternatively you could make sure, nobody has access rights to the data in the database. I.e. you could encrypt everything and make sure only the CEO has the certificate to encrypt the data ;).

If you *cannot* be sure that your software *will not be hacked*, there is only one way to make the system secure: No *digitized* signature at all, only *digital signature*. Every customer gets his own digital certificate and is responsible for it. The signature needs to be performed digitally with this certificate. Of course, lots of possibilities for abuse, but you've delegated the risk to the customer.

**Conclusion**

No system is ever totally secure and it is most important to get the requirements straight. Otherwise it gets expensive quickly. There are always many options for abuse, make sure that your certificates cannot be accessed by people who shouldn't be allowed to.

Comment: i thought what you mentioned was actually an electronic signature, upon paying closer attention to the provided link form the american government it is indeed not about digitized signatures this was a fault on my behalve.
1 question though, if i delete my private key how am i ever getting back the stroke information, should that not be accessible to prove (with bezier curve) that it is actually that persons handwriting?

Comment: In the strategy that I explained, the data is not encrypted at all, it is only signed. So the information is always present. You probably should encrypt the information in the database, to avoid abuse of the saved stroke info, but that needs to be done with a different key/certificate. As I say, destroying the key is insecure anyways. You can just use it as starting point for your concept...